# Current research on indoor localization and navigation in changing environment?

Tags: machine-learning, path-planning, scene-classification

I'm trying to get up to speed on the latest research regarding indoor localization, scene classification, navigation in changing environment, etc.

Any advice would be appreciated, but I'm especially interested in recent research papers from vetted sources.

Comment: I would kindly request you to check out community guidelines for your insightful knowledge.

Comment: @quintumnia I don't understand the request. What should I do and what should be the outcome of such action?

Comment: we have guidelines,which we follow here.

Comment: @quintumnia That doesn't answer any of my question. Is something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I would start with:

- [PoseNet: A Convolutional Network for Real-Time 6-DOF Camera Relocalization](https://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_iccv_2015/papers/Kendall_PoseNet_A_Convolutional_ICCV_2015_paper.pdf)
- [VidLoc: A Deep Spatio-Temporal Model for 6-DoF Video-Clip Relocalization](http://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_cvpr_2017/papers/Clark_VidLoc_A_Deep_CVPR_2017_paper.pdf)
- [Image-based localization using LSTMs for structured feature correlation](http://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_ICCV_2017/papers/Walch_Image-Based_Localization_Using_ICCV_2017_paper.pdf)
- [Image-based Localization using Hourglass Networks](http://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_ICCV_2017_workshops/papers/w17/Melekhov_Image-Based_Localization_Using_ICCV_2017_paper.pdf)
- [UAN: Unified Attention Network for Convolutional Neural Networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.05376.pdf)
- [Scene Coordinate and Correspondence Learning for Image-Based
  Localization](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.08443.pdf)

You can also search for articles using the 7-scenes dataset ([Scene Coordinate Regression Forests for Camera Relocalization in RGB-D Images](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6619221)) which is pretty standard

Comment: Welcome to SE:AI and thanks for contributing!  (I've edited the question to include the titles of the papers, with links embedded.  Please follow this protocol in future, since links can expire, and posting web addresses reduces readability.)